# Enable PHP on macOS Server 5.6

Tags: server.app, apache

In the most recent update to macOS Server 5.6, Apple had removed quite a number of services from the Server application in favor of built-in services in the system itself. However, now that the Website service's panel is removed, I can't find a way to turn on PHP for the Server.

I tried the default apache config in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, but that didn't work.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is PHP installed on your system and what change did you specifically make to your `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: @Allan The standard way. PHP is installed by default on macOS, and I un-commented the LoadModule line for PHP module.